# Google Play Services in an Android Studio 0.1.1 gradle project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

The latest update to Android studio does not allow one to access the project structure GUI from a project that uses gradle. Although I have configured the gradle script to use google play services, for some reason I am still unable to use the library. Here is what I did:

1. Created a new Android project
2. Created a folder named "libraries" in the root directory of the
   project
3. Copied the google-play-services folder into "libraries" and renamed
   it to "google-play-services"
4. Created a build.gradle file in the "google-play-services" folder with the following contents:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'android-library'
>
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
>
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
> }
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 17
>     buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'
>
>     sourceSets {
>         main {
>             manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
>             java.srcDirs = ['src']
>             resources.srcDirs = ['src']
>             aild.srcDirs = ['src']
>             renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
>             res.srcDirs = ['res']
>             assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

5.) Edited my project's build.gradle with the following:

> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
>     }
> }
> apply plugin: 'android'
>
> dependencies {
>     compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
>     compile project(':libraries:google-play-services')
> }
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 17
>     buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         minSdkVersion 15
>         targetSdkVersion 17
>     }
> }
> ```

6.) Changed my settings.gradle to the following

```
include ':Rimatyo', ':libraries:google-play-services'
```

Everything compiles fine, but I cam unable to access any Google play services class from my project. All the guides I've seen online utilize the project structure GUI, which isn't possible anymore. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Was able to get around the problem by importing a google play service sample app posted by Xavier Ducrohet in the adt-dev Google group and refactoring everything to make it match my project structure. Not ideal, but everything is working.

Answer (score 9):

There is now [official support for Google Play services](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try building the project first from the command line and then importing it into Studio? If that works, then you are hitting this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55784